# C++ clearing a std::map with internal lists

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdlist

If I have a std::map like this `std::map<int, std::list<int> > myMap;`

After the map has been populated with lists and I wish to clear all elements later, is it simply enough to do `myMap.clear();` , or should I first go through each element in the map and clear each list first?

Comment: Destruction happens recursively for all member objects and base type objects. `clear()` will destroy nodes, which will destroy the contained data and if that data happens to be an object with destructor that will be called.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just use `myMap.clear()`. It takes care of all necessary cleanup.

More precisely, it `delete`s each node in the tree, and as every node is a `std::pair<int, std::list<int>>`, the deletion causes the destructor `std::list::~list` to be invoked - and this destructor takes care of the cleanup of the data it owns.

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't certain about this one.